# MySQL date import issue

Tags: python, mysql, django, date, django-orm

I have the following MySQL database table:

```
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| fixtureid                 | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| fixturedate               | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I wish to pull in some data from an xmlsoccer.com website but it is returned in the following format "2015-08-01T11:45:00+00:00".

When I try to import it I get the following error:

> Exception Type:   ValueError Exception Value:  MySQL backend does not
>   support timezone-aware datetimes when USE_TZ is False.

My django code is as follows:

```
fixtureUpdate = StraightredFixture(fixtureid=fixture['Id'],
                                   away_team_id = fixture['AwayTeam_Id'],
                                   home_team_id = fixture['HomeTeam_Id'],
                                   fixturedate = fixture['Date'])             

fixtureUpdate.save()
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction to make the date MySQL friendly that would be great.  Many thanks, Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an error message points out you should either:

- enable timezone support by setting [`USE_TZ = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/)
- remove timezone part from your dates before saving them to database